# Loading local storage items for multiple dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to make a table with multiple dropdowns, which all have the same values but different ID's which should retain values even after refreshing or closing and opening the page again.
It has to run on a local computer without php or any server sided scripting and without any addons, so standard browser configuration.

I've searched a lot on google and found:
[local storage for multiple select option dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321711/local-storage-for-multiple-select-option-dropdowns)
which helps with keeping the data, but as soon as I close the browser and load it again. The values are gone.
Can somebody help me figure this out?
Thanks in advance.

example of the code as requested:

```
<select name="1" id="1" class="test">
   <option value="-">-</option>
   <option value="Mike">Mike</option> 
   <option value="Steven">Steven</option> 
   <option value="Sacha">Sacha</option> 
   <option value="Wilfried">Wilfried</option> 
   <option value="Kevin">Kevin</option> 
   <option value="Stefan">Stefan</option> 
   <option value="Koen">Koen</option> 
   <option value="Wasil">Wasil</option> 
</select>
<select name="2" id="2" class="test">
   <option value="-">-</option>
   <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
   <option value="Steven">Steven</option>
   <option value="Sacha">Sacha</option>
   <option value="Wilfried">Wilfried</option>
   <option value="Kevin">Kevin</option>
   <option value="Stefan">Stefan</option>
   <option value="Koen">Koen</option>
   <option value="Wasil">Wasil</option>
 </select>
```

this is the js file.

```
 $('.test').change(function() {
      localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
 }).val(function() {
   return localStorage.getItem(this.id)
 });
```

Comment: You could start by giving some of your current code and then people will help you.

Comment: ok, done, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you added some code :) I've tested exactly your code and it worked. Check this Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/96hrybu2/

Your problem might be that you are not binding the elements correctly.

Try to change your code to this:

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.test').change(function() {
              localStorage.setItem(this.id, this.value);
            }).val(function() {
               return localStorage.getItem(this.id)
            });
       });
```

What seems to be happening is that he tries to bind those elements faster then they are rendered in the DOM.

Either that or your browser doesnt support localStorage.

Let me know if it helped.

Also check your console for some kind of errors and don't forget to add the jQuery library but I guess you know that :P

Cheers.

Comment: No problem bro :P A 1+ would be appreciated.